# A kind of converse to the Hopf theorem on ergodicity of geodesic flow in negative curvature

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, ds.dynamical-systems, ergodic-theory

Is  there a  2  dimensional  Riemannian  manifold $M$  whose curvature is  not  negative  but  its  geodesic  flow is  an  ergodic  flow?

Comment: @thedude  but am I mistaken to think that it is not ergodic because the unit tangent bundle possess two disjoint copy of the torus $T^2$ which separate the unit tangent bundle and is invariant under the geodesic flow?

Comment: @RW What is the argument for ergodicity? May I ask you to read my previous comment?

Comment: @Ali Taghavi - Oups - sorry - of course the geodesic flow on the torus is not ergodic - since the slope is preserved

Comment: I believe that if $M$ is a closed hyperbolic surface, and if you then alter the metric to be negatively curved except at a single point of zero curvature, the resulting geodesic flow will still be ergodic. I do not have a proof at hand.

Comment: @AliTaghavi A torus geodesic with irrational slope will come arbitrarily close to any point. Is this not your definition of ergodic?

Comment: @thedude No - please check carefully the definition of ergodicity and the definition of the geodesic flow.

Comment: @AliTaghavi I thought the geodesic flow was defined on the manifold, but now I see it is defined on the tangent bundle. So I learned something from your question. Thank you.

Comment: @thedude  You  are  well  come  and  thank you for  your  attention to my question.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It was proved by [Donnay](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=970551) that any compact orientable surface can be given a Riemannian metric for which the geodesic flow is ergodic. See [Theorem 1 of  this article.](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007%2FBFb0082827) On the other hand, there are no negatively curved metrics on a sphere or a torus.

Answer (score 5):

Anosov flows are ergodic and a geodesic flow can be Anosov even if the curvature is not strictly negative. This was studied by Eberlein in the seventies, in an article from 1973 entitled *when is a geodesic flow of Anosov type?* and other authors (Klingenberg etc).

A byproduct of this study is the following: on a nonpositively curved surface, the geodesic flow is of Anosov type as soon as there is a point of negative curvature on all geodesics. So you can start with a surface with negative curvature, make a small perturbation so that the curvature vanishes on a single point $p$, and the geodesic flow is still Anosov and ergodic. Now the Anosov condition is an open one so you can make again a small perturbation so that the curvature becomes positive at the point $p$ and you still have an ergodic Anosov geodesic flow. There are many variations around these ideas.

Comment: Thank you very  much  for  this  very  great  answer. I  am  sorry that I  can  not  accept  the two  answers  simultaneously.   https://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/1491/why-cant-i-accept-two-answers-to-the-same-question-simultaneously

Comment: But  a  slight perturbation of  a  compact  surface  with  strictly negative  curvature is  stile  a surface  with  strictly  negative  curvature. Am  I  right? But  i  think that there  is  modification of your  argument.  I  try  to  find  the  valuable  reference you mentioned  in your  answer and  learn  them. thanks  again  for  your attention to my question and these very helpful references

Comment: The curvature is zero at a point, the flow is Anosov, you make a perturbation such that the curvature becomes positive around the point and the flow stays Anosov.